# How to Avoid 'Data truncated for column' in Mysql Database Using java?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

In my Java Program ..Hibernate Bean class define one column like..

**TimtableVO.java**

```
@Column(name="REPEAT_DAYS")
private WeekdayType repeatDays;//hear WeekdayType is Enum Class
```

And in my service class i'm using this TimetableVO.java bean class as..

This is my Service class:

```
public void createEvent(TimetableVO timetableVO) {
    WeekdayType weekday = null;
    for (String day : timetableVO.getTemp().split(",")) {
        weekday = WeekdayType.valueOf(day);
    }
    timetableVO.setRepeatDays(weekday);
    userDAO.createEvent(timetableVO);
}
```

And my DAO class i'm inserting timetableVO object..

```
public void createEvent(TimetableVO timetableVO) throws DataAccessException {
    entityManager.persist(timetableVO);
}
```

But Exception will come..

```
Exception: Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncated for column 'REPEAT_DAYS' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2045)
    at coHibernate: insert into EC_TIMETABLE (CLASS_DURATION, COURSE_DURATION, COURSE_FEE, END_DATE, REPEAT_COUNT, REPEAT_DAYS, REPEAT_TYPE, SEARCH_KEY, START_DATE, S_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
m.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1468)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column 'REPEAT_DAYS' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
```

**EDIT:**
This is my WeekdayType Enum

```
public enum WeekdayType {
    MONDAY(Calendar.MONDAY), TUESDAY(Calendar.TUESDAY), WEDNESDAY(
    Calendar.WEDNESDAY), THURSDAY(Calendar.THURSDAY), FRIDAY(
    Calendar.FRIDAY), SATURDAY(Calendar.SATURDAY), SUNDAY(
    Calendar.SUNDAY);

    private int day;

    private WeekdayType(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }
}
```

Comment: show us your WeekdayType

Comment: what is data type for column `REPEAT_DAYS`

Comment: an Enum type.... ie., WeekdayType.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like the error is due the fact that the column `REPEAT_DAYS` is too small to save the values you're passing via the `WeekdayType` Enum. So recheck the definition of that column in your underling database and eventually increase it's size.

Also you're missing an annotation:

```
 @Column(name="REPEAT_DAYS", length="45")
 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 private WeekdayType repeatDays;
```

The `length` in the annotation should match the length of your column in your DB schema.

Comment: Actually when ever create Database in that time i wrote Enum('MONDAY','TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY','THURSDAY','FRIDAY','SATURDAY','SUNDAY') just like this only...how to define it's length?

Comment: Are you creating the DB schema via Hibernate?

Comment: NO.. i'm using Phpadmin for Db and remove the property of hbm2ddl.auto

Answer (score 22):

This can be caused by an `ENUM` in your table schema that doesn't have all the values you are trying to insert.  Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event (
    weekday_type ENUM(
        'SUNDAY',
        'MONDAY',
        'TUESDAY',
        'WEDNESDAY',
        'THURSDAY',
        'FRIDAY'
    ) NOT NULL
);
```

Then when you execute an insert like

```
INSERT INTO event (weekday_type) VALUES ('SATURDAY');
```

using JDBC you get an exception like: `Data truncated for column 'weekday_type' at row 1` because you forgot to include `SATURDAY` in your table definition.  When the insert happens, the value gets `truncated` to nothing.

Comment: this! i have the same problem and then when i check my table definition, there is a typo `THRUSDAY` instead of `THURSDAY`

Answer (score 1):

Your server seems to run in strict mode and you might try to insert NULL in a NOT NULL column.

See also here: [What is this error? "Database query failed: Data truncated for column 'column_name' at row 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704304/what-is-this-error-database-query-failed-data-truncated-for-column-column-na)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your tables are auto generated by hibernate, you cant annotate Enum type like you did

> @Column(name="REPEAT_DAYS")
>
> private WeekdayType repeatDays;

Check `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` annotation

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs only when you are trying to insert a value which is too long for an column to hold.
In your case, the column definition for `REPEAT_DAYS` is not enough to hold your value.
Also your you cannot annotate an enum type like

```
@Column(name="REPEAT_DAYS")

private WeekdayType repeatDays;
```

Instead you can do something like

`@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` and define your enum like this

```
enum Fruits {
  apple,
  orange
}
```