# Mysql 5.5, how to avoid varchar field truncation error for executing session

Tags: hibernate, configuration, truncation, mysql-5.5

**Mysql 5.5, how to avoid varchar field truncation error, for executing session.**

I'm using java hibernate mysql 5.5

I'm looking for something like:

```
set SESSION sqlMode="AUTO_TRUNCATE_FIELDS"
```

instead of getting an error.

**Is it possible to do it in a programatic way for the current executing session?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I've implemented via java-connection.mysql as shown here:

```
userDAO.s.doWork(
        new Work() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Connection arg0) throws SQLException {
                DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = arg0.getMetaData();
                ResultSet rs=databaseMetaData.getColumns(null, null, "event", "%");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    if ("title".equals(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"))) {
                        titleColumSize=rs.getInt("COLUMN_SIZE");
                    }
                }
        }
        }
    );
```

then:

```
if (title.length()>titleColumSize)
    title=title.substring(0, titleColumSize-7)+" [...]";
```

**If any configuration solution is available I will appreciate!! Thanks!**

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but most probably there isn't (without modifying some global DBMS parameter). A related discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950579/how-to-avoid-data-truncated-for-column-in-mysql-database-using-java

Comment: Yes I haven't try it but I think strict_mode set off should work, but it affects many other settings: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-other-changes-strict-mode.html